# How to do loop menu in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to do loop menu with some basic functions, everything is working fine apart of looping menu
in my opinion i have something wrong with while loop but i can't figure out what it is.

```
int main(void) {

char letter;
char status = 0;
printf ("--------------------------------------\n");
  printf("a – Calculate the area of a rectangle\n");
  printf("b – Calculate the area of a circle\n");
  printf("c – Display a multiplication table\n");
  printf("d – Add two numbers\n");
  printf("x - exit program\n");
printf ("--------------------------------------\n");

scanf("%c",&letter);



while (status == 0)
{

  if (letter == 'a' || letter == 'A')
  {
  } 
   if (letter == 'b'|| letter == 'B')
  {
  }  

   if(letter == 'c'|| letter == 'C')
  {
  }


   if (letter == 'd'|| letter == 'D')
  {
  }

  if(letter == 'x' || letter == 'X')
  {
    printf("shut down\n");
    break;
  }
status ++
} 
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pace a `scanf(" %c",&letter);` inside the loop body; otherwise, you will not get a chance to ever enter an `x`...

Please note the space before the `%c`, i.e. the `" %c"`-format, which captures any new line in the input buffer from a previous input.

Answer (score 0):

1. Maybe you meant that status will be `int` and not `char`?
2. You should read input also in the beginning of loop, otherwise you will take only one input
3. After the first iteration, you advance status so it will exit the loop. Is this what you tried to achieve? I guess you meant for:

```c
if(letter == 'x' || letter == 'X')
{
    printf("shut down\n");
    status ++
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop will run only one time cause 'status ++' will work no matter the condition you should use it inside the x case -

```
    if(letter == 'x' || letter == 'X')
    {
      printf("shut down\n");
      status ++;
    }
```

This should break your loop only after 'x' is entered.